# cannot run multiple statements in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have created the MySql procedure which create multiple tables and insert data, and if data do not current then remove it and show the messages in mysql command line or my sql workbench.. For this i used variable and then display like following it is working fine in mysql.

```
SET _output = 'Generating table one...'; 
select _output;

create table ec_ms_yy_qt
(select * from table1);
call checkdata();

SET _output = 'Generating table tow..'; 
select _output;
```

If i called same from php it stop after first statement and do not execute the procedure.
It only return 'Generating table one...'; . It mean stop running if found the select statement

```
$rs = mysql_query( ‘CALL processdata()’ );
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
  print_r($row);
}
```

Then I removed the select _output from store procedure it working fine. But this is not solution i want , user will not informed by any error occur and where it was raised. It also hanged the program till procedure finished and browse show on status bar waiting for localhost.

Comment: Are you sure it's not running the procedure? I suspect `mysql_query()` may only be able to fetch the rows from the first query. Everything else runs, you just can't get those rows.

Comment: mysql_* will only run one query at a time to help mitigate injection attacks. The first should evaluate like you said, but the others should be ignored if operating correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This is a feature of PHPs MySQL extension trying to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection) (to some extend). Please note the [`mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension in PHP is deprecated, unmaintained and should not be used when writing new PHP scripts. The [deprecation is documented](http://php.net/mysql_query) in the manual. The documentation on `mysql_query()` also clearly states:

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (**multiple queries are not supported**) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

Note that the new [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) extension, which is a replacement for the original `mysql` extension, has a special function to allow multiple statements in one query string: [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli("xxxxx", "root", "xxxxx", "xxxx");
$mysqli->connect_errno;
$sql = "call processdata()";
$res=$mysqli->multi_query($sql) ;
echo $res;

Comment: Thanks it is working...but one problem it is working on background on mysql server on browser it echo 1... and do not display the output messages which in between in procedure.. ? How can i store all the messsages one by on and display on the screen so user can know the  current status of procedure (All query in one procedures) $mysqli = new mysqli("xxxxx", "root", "xxxxx", "xxxx");
$sql = "call processdata()";
$res=$mysqli->multi_query($sql) ;
echo $res;

Comment: I add the following code and the output messages show on the screen all togther, but after complete all queries of the  procedure and browse is hanged till this..$res=$mysqli->multi_query($sql) ;
do {
    if ($res = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        var_dump($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
        $res->free();
    }
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());